# AWS Lambda Backlog for S3 events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am wondering how Lambda handles a backlog of S3 events when Lambda is throttled and can't keep up with events. Will S3 events be queued and for how long?

The hypothetical scenario is that a lambda function is being triggered by POST events on a S3 bucket and its concurrency limit is 10. Suppose there are suddenly a few million POST events...will those events be queued and how much time is allowed for the set of 10 lambda instances to process this steam of events?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the invocation (triggered by `S3 Events Rule`) follows the same behavior as you would trigger your Lambda through `AWS SDK`, `AWS CLI`, etc.

Which means that a lot of the `few million POST events` you mentioned in your hypothetical scenario will not be processed and even the retries will not work for all of the events.

As long as you didn't setup a DLQ (Dead Letter Queue) these events were discard and you dont have a chance to recover them.

I linked some articles to find more informations about the behavior of AWS Lambda.

[AWS Lambda - Understanding Retry Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html)

> Asynchronous invocation – Asynchronous events are queued before being
>   used to invoke the Lambda function. If AWS Lambda is unable to fully
>   process the event, it will automatically retry the invocation twice,
>   with delays between retries.

[AWS Lambda - Dead Letter Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html)

> AWS Lambda directs events that cannot be processed to the specified
>   Amazon SNS topic or Amazon SQS queue. Functions that don't
>   specify a DLQ will discard events after they have exhausted their
>   retries.